# How to design views for iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, ios8

We all knows that Apple will be launching iPhone 6 on Sept 09, and also they are going to increase iPhone 6 size (width and height). I have a question that is what would be the exact frame size in pixel? How we can design views for iPhone 6? as am going to start a new app. Please advise me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to guess what exactly an iPhone 6 will be as there is lack of official technical information. The approach I can suggest you is to use image assets, autolayout and the whole adaptive UI. You can find information on each topic over the web but I would highly recommend you to watch a movies from WWDC([WWDC 2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/), [WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/)). You can start with `What's new in Cocoa Touch` and then for example `Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit`. In each movie they recommend other related session so what's new is always a good point to start.

Comment: Thanks for giving reply.

Comment: hope it will help you :)